# mocha : how to run multiple JS test files under separate process environment

Tags: environment-variables, mocha.js

I am new to Mocha so this might probably be a trivial question but couldn't yet find an answer:

I have a simple NodeJS project with the below package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "davide talesco",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

and the following 2 tests files under test folder:

**test1.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();

describe('Test setProp', function(){
  it('env variable should be test', function(done){
    process.env.NODE_ENV.should.be.equal('test');
    return done();
  });
});
```

**test2.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'prod';

var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();

describe('Test setProp', function(){
  it('env variable should be prod', function(done){
    process.env.NODE_ENV.should.be.equal('prod');
    return done();
  });
});
```

when I run npm test the first test complete succesfully whilst the second fails as per below

```
ie-macp-davidt:crap davide_talesco$ npm test

> pc-lib@1.0.0 test /Users/davide_talesco/development/crap
> mocha



  Test setProp
    1) env variable should be test

  Test setProp
    ✓ env variable should be prod


  1 passing (16ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test setProp env variable should be test:

      AssertionError: expected 'prod' to equal 'test'
      + expected - actual

      -prod
      +test

      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test1.js:11:36)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

its pretty clear that the tests are running under the same process...
my question is : how can I make them run under completely separate processes so each one can set its own environment?

Thanks,

Davide

Answer (score 5):

One of the most simple ways is to use Unix `find` command:

`find ./test -name '*.js' -exec mocha \{} \;`

I'd recommend to use local `mocha` binaries to avoid troubles in case it isn't installed globally:

`find ./test -name '*.js' -exec ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \{} \;`

If you want to add that to *package.json*, please note that backslashes should be escaped:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "find ./test -name '*.js' -exec ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \\{} \\;"
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort testing as soon as a test file fails, you can do it like this:

```
find ./test -type f -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'for n; do ./node_modules/.bin/mocha "$n" || exit 1; done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`mocha-parallel-tests`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-parallel-tests).

To install:
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-parallel-tests`

To use:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha-parallel-tests"
  },
```

Nice thing is that it is a proper mocha runner so you can configure reports and pass standard mocha configuration like bail.

Comment: This option no longer works with the latest mocha, as the package hasn't been updated in awhile.